# Async Google Maps API v3 undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous

I'm writing an app that loads Google Maps asynchronously with a hand-built framework.
When I load maps it will not load all of it for some reason and I'll end up with a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. I checked chrome inspector and found out that `google.maps` is a valid object, but it has none of its own properties. I manually call the "initialize function" well after the document has loaded. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Perhaps some code (your "hand-built framework would be a start)?  A link to a page that exhibits the problem? A jsfiddle that does?

Comment: Reading the documentation is a good start [**See**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#asynch)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can't load the  maps-API asynchronous with the well-known URL( http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false )

When you take a look at the script-file, you'll see, that this is not the API that gets loaded, it's a loader that loads the API. The loader   makes use of `document.write()` , what will lead you to unexpected results when called after the document has been loaded.

Furthermore the onload-event of the document doesn't wait for asynchronous loaded objects, it may come too quick.

You also cannot use the load-event of the script to invoke the initialize-function, because when it fires, the loader is loaded, not the maps-API.

**What to do:**
append a callback-parameter to the script-URL(with the name of the initialize-function as value)

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initialize`

Now you get a different loader which:

1. doesn't use `document.write()`
2. calls the callback-function(initialize) when the maps-API has been loaded

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7cu2F/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7cu2F/)

---

**Related to the comment**: *seems the callback has to be a function attached to window directly. not cool google :)*

There is another option, [the google-API-loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/) which supports the usage of function-references (instead of function-names).

Sample, which loads the maps-API asynchronously, but only when there is an element with the ID `map-canvas` in the document, and then creates a map:

```js
    window.addEventListener('load',function(){
      if(document.getElementById('map-canvas')){
        google.load("maps", "3",{
          callback:function(){
             new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
                zoom: 3
              });
          }
        });     
      }
    },false);
```

```css
      body,html,#map-canvas{
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:100%;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. I didn't want to use the `callback=initialize` because I wanted to pass some extra arguments in the initialize function, but I guess I'll have to work around it.

Comment: seems the `callback` has to be a function attached to window directly. not cool google :)

Comment: @apneadiving: The google-API-loader would be an option in this case, see my edited answer.

Comment: @Dr.Molle 1 in 5 page loads still gives the error with that script. Is caching involved on Google's end or something?

Comment: There is another great solution that worked for me. It is about using Google API Loader (explained [here](http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-load-the-google-maps-places-library-through-google-api-loader/comment-page-1/#comment-175489)).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/loader/ is 404