# Lazy loading Google Places API v3 library not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-places

I am trying to *lazy load* the [Google Places API library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) as needed in my application

I have tried two ways, neither of which seem to load the Places library.

First, using `jQuery`:

```
url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true';
$.getScript(url).then(function() {
  console.log(window.google.maps.places);
});
```

This logs `undefined`.

Second, using native javascript:

```
script        = document.createElement('script')
script.type   = 'text/javascript'
script.src    = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true'
script.onload = function() { console.log(window.google.maps.places); }
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

This also logs `undefined`.

This places library does not seem to be loading or initializing. `window.google.maps` is available, but I don't understand why the `places` library isn't loading. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Async Google Maps API v3 undefined is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184956/async-google-maps-api-v3-undefined-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Very real duplicate! Thanks!