# Primefaces gmap doesn't show after click on p:commandButton (ReferenceError: google is not defined )

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I see gmap just after update page. If I don't update page I get error in chrome console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined index.xhtml:1
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/layout_template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="windowTitle">
            Admin Panel
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>            

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Map</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p:gmap type="roadmap" center="50.00, 28.00" zoom="8" style="width: 1000px; height: 400px;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            </h:form>

            <!--<h:outputScript name="app/google-map-loader.js" library="js" target="head"/>-->
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript">
            </script>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</h:body>
</html>
```

My footer template

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
        >

<body>
<ui:composition>
    <div class="bottom-nav footer"> 2013 &copy; by Me</div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <h:outputScript name="lib/bootstrap.min.js" library="js" target="body"/>
    <h:outputScript name="app/smooth-sliding-menu.js" library="js" target="body"/>
</ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

I read in doc [image: script position]

But I don't want put gmap script in head of main template. Is it posiible to make it work without redirect. And is it possible to add script in head of child template

Comment: You can execute/call a JavaScript method at any time and you don't need a redirect to achieve it. For the second question, you can use `h:outputScript` in child templates.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan I can't put external url inside `h:outputScipt`

Comment: `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true|false"></script>` should work inside a child template wrapped by a form. What's wrong ?

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan I get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined'.

Comment: Try to load the script before loading gmap. Put the script tag before gmap.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan It doesn't help

Comment: Add `&callback=initialize` to the script's URL. You might have encountered this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184956/async-google-maps-api-v3-undefined-is-not-a-function/14185834#14185834)

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan with 'callback' appears new exception http://i.imgur.com/8xWmacY.png

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this problem. On previous page I have p:commandButton

```
<p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.navigateToDashboard()}" ajax="false"
                                 styleClass="btn btn-default btn-block"/>
```

I doesn't have **ajax="false"** attribute but page was changed I don't know why. Now, with non-ajax submit I don't get any problems.