# How do I add google map in angular.js controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

So, I'm fairly new to angular and having hard time implementing google map API. I keep getting error:

```
Uncaught InvalidValueError: initialize is not a function.
```

I have this for the script tag:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY API KEY GOES HERE&callback=initialize"
    async defer></script>
```

But since my function initialize() is inside my controller, it doesn't recognize it. If I put the function outside of the controller, it does recognize it. But since I have all the data defined within the controller, I need this inside it. I'm not even sure what I'm supposed to ask but I just need to get the map to show up. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is a double of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184956/async-google-maps-api-v3-undefined-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Could you explain this in easier terms? I read it a couple of times and still having hard time.

Comment: I think you should add libraries of geometry and places so you can see places

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could consider to load Google Maps API *synchronously* as demonstrated below

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      
       $scope.initialize = function() {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), {
             center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
             zoom: 8
          });
       }    
       
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', $scope.initialize);   

    });
```

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
#map_div {
        height: 480px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" ></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div id="map_div"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @AlexP, via query string, for example: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=-YOUR-KEY-GOES-HERE- `

Comment: So I need to put `  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myInitialize&callback=initialize"></script>
` into the main page (the one that contains `<div data-ng-view></div>` ? Because I have still the same error described here even after implementing your solutin

Comment: @AlexP, that's right, but **without** `callback` parameter, in my case google map is getting initialized once the page is loaded:  `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', $scope.initialize); `

Comment: is it possible to refresh manually from Controller and ask to  load it when I need it and not on page load? As I still have no effect :(

Comment: UPD: it appeared only once and doesn't want to reappear after refresh of whole page

Comment: Thanks. I have managed to achieve my goal by assigning new `map` every time I wanted to refresh it. `$window.map=map;` . Your comments helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to read this [documentation](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) and use simple googlemap angularjs directive.

I hope this works for you

All The best