# initializing the google map api in angularjs function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to initialize the google maps init function from a function, the working of function is to add a new `div` tag which will contain a map.
I tried code written in commented area below inside a function but it's not working but its working outside the function.

```
app.controller('controller1', function($scope, $http, $window) {

$scope.addMapPanel = function() {

    var ref_div = angular.element(document.querySelector('#ref_div'));

    var map_div = angular.element(document.querySelector('#map_div'));

    if(map_div.length){
        console.log('exist');
    }else{
        console.log('doesnot');
        ref_div.append('<div class="col-md-6" id="map_div"></div>');
    }

    /*$scope.initialize = function() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), {
         center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
         zoom: 8
      });
   }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', $scope.initialize);*/

  };
});
```

similar type answer : [How do I add google map in angular.js controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639986/how-do-i-add-google-map-in-angular-js-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You still need to have the `DomListener` call some function once that library has been loaded. From there, just check to see if the div exists. If not, you need to append it and then initialize a map onto that div.

However, I would recommend using `directives` for DOM interaction, as that is where View logic should exist in the MVC architecture. Plus, it allows reuse.

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('mapController', function($scope) {
    $scope.initialize = function () {
      
      var ref_div = angular.element(document.querySelector('#ref_div'));

      var map_div = angular.element(document.querySelector('#map_div'));

      if(map_div.length){
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), {
           center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
           zoom: 8
        });
      }else{
          ref_div.append('<div class="col-md-6" id="map_div"></div>');
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), {
           center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
           zoom: 8
        });
      }
    };

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', $scope.initialize);

});
```

```css
#map_div {
   width: 150px;
   height:  150px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="ref_div" ng-app="app" ng-controller="mapController">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>
```