# JS errors loading Google Maps API asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184956/) question, I have added `&callback=initialize` to the script that loads the Google Maps API:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX&amp;callback=initialize&amp;region=it&amp;libraries=places" async defer></script>
```

The map loads, but directions don't anymore and I get the following errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at map.html:15

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at initialize (map.html:60)
    at js?key=XXXX&callback=initialize&region=it&libraries=places:130
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is the function (I have changed the GPS coords and removed info from label/address for privacy):

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var mkArray=[];

function initialize() {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.389835,12.413704);

var mapOptions = {
    zoom:16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: myLatlng,
    styles: [
        {
            featureType: "poi.business",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                    { visibility: "off" }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

var input = document.getElementById('start');
var options = {
    types: ['geocode'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'it'},
    rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE
};
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.76, 12.33),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.00, 12.64)
);
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
autocomplete.setBounds(bounds);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'XXXXX'
});
mkArray.push(marker);
}

function calcRoute(callback) {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = "Address, Rome";
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

        // If a callback was passed, run it
        if(typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }

      }
    });
    for (var i = 0, j = mkArray.length; i < j; i++) 
      mkArray[i].setMap(null);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `google` object before loading it:

`var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()`

You need to wait for your callback `initialize` to be executed to use `google` object, so my best advise is to do something like this (as you already did for `directionsDisplay`):

```
var directionService;

function initialize() {
   directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

   // other code here
}
```

And on your last line what are you trying to do?

`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

You're making 2 errors here:

1. Still trying to use `google` before your callback gets called
2. You're trying to register the same function for both GMaps API callback and window `load` event. This won't work because of first point, but even if it did you would end up executing `initialize` twice and I don't think it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense (and it works!) - the last line was a leftover.. thanks for catching it :)